# Import certain .csv columns and ignore others

Tags: r, csv, import

Help appreciated here.

I've got a propietary .CSV file (too large to edit) with more columns than data in it, such as:

```
col1  col2  col3 .... col98  col99
id1    1     tim       ""      ""    ""    ""
......
```

Notice the double quotes for every field and that there are more data than header.

I would like to read only those columns I know for certain have data (e.g. col1, col2, col3), and ignore the ones which have a double quote (") or no data or no corresponding header (col 98-99, and the 2 extra unnamed columns).

I tried to read it using `read.csv` but unfortunately it throws an error for columns without data (that is, with tempty quotes):

```
td= read.csv(file.choose(), header = T, as.is = T, sep='"')
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that csv stands for comma-separated values which is not the case here; however, we can still use `read.csv` like this:

```
Lines <- 'col1  col2  col3 col98  col99
id1    1     tim       ""      ""'

DF <- read.csv(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE, sep = "", quote = '"')
```

giving:

```
  col1 col2 col3 col98 col99
1  id1    1  tim    NA    NA
```

If you only want certain columns whose column numbers are known then:

```
> DF[1:3]
  col1 col2 col3
1  id1    1  tim
```

or to detect and remove columns of NAs:

```
DF[!apply(is.na(DF), 2, all)]
```

giving:

```
  col1 col2 col3
1  id1    1  tim
```

Comment: Thanks G.G., I tried but it didnt work. It may be because all fields appear enclosed in quotes? I'm modifying the question right away.

Comment: If *not work* means you were unable to read the data then there is a difference between your data and your question since the code shown in this answer reads in both your original and revised data.  I have expanded the answer to show how to remove columns.

Comment: Apologies, I have completed the question accordingly. There were rows with data that had no header, and that was causing the reading issue.

Comment: If the number of column headers does not match the data you can use `skip = 1, header = FALSE` to skip the header row.   If different lines of data have different numbers of fields then you can use `fill = TRUE`.